why the changes in next.js code is not reflecting in docker container localhost?
I am on development phase of my next.js application. I have dockerized it using docker compose. My main goal is to reflect any changes that I do in my local env to the docker container files so that whatever I change on the UI, I can view it without doing docker-compose up --build again and again. so I have mounted the files using docker volumes.
Issue:
Any changes I do in my local files, it's getting changed in docker container too, I can view that by doing docker-compose exec web sh. But on UI the changes are not reflecting.
I don't know it's relevant or not but one thing I can see that .next folder and .eslintrc.json file is not getting copied to the docker container. Also i don't have a .dockerignore file in the project folder.
I am not able to understand why the local changes are not getting reflected to UI which is running on a docker container. I am attaching the code for the reference.
Dockerfile.dev
FROM node:22-alpine3.19

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN echo npm -v
RUN echo node -v
RUN echo npx next -v

COPY ./ ./

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]

docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app

I am expecting that whatever changes I am doing in my next.js project on my local machine, should reflect on the UI which is running inside a docker container instantly.

If you're in the development phase still, do you need Docker at all?  Especially given what you've shown, I might use plain Node without Docker.  The volumes: setup can introduce some complexity (for example adding dependencies to package.json will have no effect) and reintroduces the "works on my system" problem since you overwrite absolutely everything in the image with local content.

I'm just trying to figure out, whether it's possible to do with docker. If possible then how? As I have mounted the volume it's copying all the files to the docker container and I can view the changes by doing sh. But still the changes are not reflected to the UI, also I can see the hidden files and folder (started with .) is not copying to the container. I am more interest to figure out the reason behind this behavior rather than just using node to fix the issue.
